# Why do the components move around when I switch one bitmap for another of the same size?

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

I'm using an ImageView to display a bitmap image that I generate. However, I want there to be no image at first, so I put in a placeholder bitmap of the same size and set its visibility to invisible.

When I programatically swap in a different bitmap of the same size, all the other components shift down the screen. I want them to stay in the same place, obviously. Where am I going wrong?

My initial layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/TextView1Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:onClick="@string/Button1OnClick"
            android:text="@string/Button1Text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ImageViewDescription"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blank_1024_200" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and my code for swapping in a different bitmap

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Both `@drawable/blank_1024_200` and `bitmap` in the code are defined as `1024x200 pixels`

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:
It seems there is something odd about either my initial dummy image or the bitmap image that I create, because if I swap to my generated image then back to the dummy image, the components don't move around, so there is some difference between my 1024x200 dummy image and my 1024x200 generated bitmap. The code I use to create the bitmap is:

```
        int BITMAP_WIDTH = 1024; // Good to make it a multiple of 16 for neat drawing
        int BITMAP_HEIGHT = 200;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with that but..

EDIT2:
I think it has to do with density. Seems that when you create an android bitmap, it has a default 'density' whereas I thought I would just get 1024x200 pixels. I don't fully understand density (in fact I don't at all) but I suspect that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understand you correct, you using `ImageView` with `height` `wrap_content`, that is why when you switch image your height changed, you should you fixed size for `ImageView` fo example `android:layout_height="300dp"`